# if loop will not stop looping

Tags: java, if-statement

my second if(output) loop, will not stop looping. 
if there are any suggestions in troubleshooting the loop?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author maxknee
 */
public class MonthTemps {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        //declare variables
        Boolean inputTest = false;
        String inputFile = inputFileName();
        String outputFile = outputFileName();
        Boolean sentinel = false;
        double highTemp, lowTemp, averageTemp, range;
        double maxTemp = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        double minTemp = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        double highSum, lowSum, yearlySum, rangeSum;
        double totalAvgHigh = 0;
        double totalAvgLow = 0;
        double totalAvgYearly = 0;
        double totalRangeAvg = 0;
        String month;
        int i = 0;

        //Exit do-while loop
        while (!inputFile.equals("exit") || (!outputFile.equals("exit")))
            {
                inputTest = inputValidName(inputFile);
                //Open files for reading
                Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(inputFile));
                //Open file for writing to.
                PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("averageTemperatures.txt");
                //Input validation for input file name
                if (inputTest)
                {

                    Boolean outputTest = outputValidName(outputFile);

                        //input validation for output file name
                        if (outputTest)
                        {
                            //Creating headers for console output and text output file                           
                            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                            System.out.println("    Month    |  High Temperature | Low Temperature | Average Temperature | Range ");
                            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                            outFile.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                            outFile.println("    Month    |  High Temperature | Low Temperature | Average Temperature | Range ");
                            outFile.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

                            //do while loop to read file
                            while (inFile.hasNext())
                            {
                                //extract Month name from file
                                month = inFile.next();
                                //Remove comma for better presentation
                                String   formatMonth = month.replace(',', ' ');
                                //calculate high temperature from text file
                                highTemp  = inFile.nextDouble();
                                //extract low temperature file from text file
                                lowTemp = inFile.nextDouble();
                                //Calculate averaget Temperature from values
                                averageTemp = (highTemp + lowTemp)/2;
                                //Calculate Range
                                range = (highTemp - lowTemp);
                                //Calculate low temperature
                                minTemp = Math.min(minTemp, lowTemp);
                                //Calculate high temperature
                                maxTemp = Math.max(maxTemp, highTemp);
                                //Sum up high temperatures
                                highSum =+ highTemp;
                                //Sum up low Temperatures
                                lowSum =+ lowTemp;
                                //calculate yearly sum
                                yearlySum =+ averageTemp;
                                //Calculate average of all the high temperatures
                                totalAvgHigh = highSum/12;
                                //Calculate average of all low temperatures
                                totalAvgLow = lowSum/12;
                                //Calculate the average of the years
                                totalAvgYearly = yearlySum/12;
                                //Calculate averge of the range
                                totalRangeAvg = (highSum +lowSum)/12;

                                System.out.println(formatMonth + "   |     " + highTemp + "         |       " + lowTemp + "     |      " + averageTemp + "    |    " + range );
                                outFile.println(formatMonth + "   |           " + highTemp + "         |       " + lowTemp + "     |      " + averageTemp + "    |    " + range );


                            }

                            //Print out calculated values
                            System.out.print("Average High Temps: " + totalAvgHigh + " Average Low Temps: " + totalAvgLow + " Total Average: " + totalAvgYearly + " Total Range Average: " + totalRangeAvg);
                            System.out.println("High Temp " + maxTemp);
                            System.out.println("Low Temp " + minTemp);
                            //Formatting
                            outFile.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                            inFile.close();
                            outFile.close();
                        }
                        //Option to crrect output file name
                        else
                        {
                            String correctOutput = correctOutputFilename();
                                outputFile = correctOutput;
                        }
                    }
                //Chance to correct input file name
                else
                {
                    String correctInput = correctInputFileName();
                    inputFile = correctInput;
                }

            }

    }


    /**
     * output corrected file name if outputfileName is wrong
     * @return
     */
    public static String correctOutputFilename() {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the correct output file name ");
        return console.next();
    }
    /**
     * input corrected file name if inputfileName is wrong
     * @return
     */
    public static String correctInputFileName() {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the correct input file name ");
        return console.next();
    }


    /**
     * collect inputFileName for the input file for program to read
     * @return
     */
    public static String inputFileName()
    {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the filename you wish to open or enter 'exit' to exit ");
        String fileName;
        fileName = console.next();
        return fileName;

    }
    /**
     * collect input for output file
     * @return
     */
    public static String outputFileName()
    {
       Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Please enter the file name you wish to output to: ");
       return console.next();
    }
    /**
     *  test to see if inputfilename is valid
     * @param inputFileName
     * @return boolean value if inputfileName is correct or not
     */
    public static Boolean inputValidName(String inputFileName)
    {
        Boolean inputName;
        if (inputFileName.equals("MonthlyTemperatures.txt"))
            {
                inputName = true;
            }
        else {inputName = false;}
        return inputName;
    }
    /**
     *  to check if outputfilename is correct
     * @param outputFileName
     * @return return boolean value if outputfilename is valid
     */
    public static Boolean outputValidName(String outputFileName)
    {
        Boolean outputName;
        if (outputFileName.equals("averageTemperatures.txt"))
        {
            outputName = true;
        }
        else {outputName = false;}
        return outputName;
    }
}
```

Comment: waaaaaaay too much code. and your question is not clear.

Comment: Do you mean the `while (inFile.hasNext())` loop?

Comment: No such thing as an "if loop".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats because your ouptutFileName doesnt change and its not if loop it is while loop going infinite.. i guess before the end of the while loop you should be taking the input from the console again . so just at the end of while loop you should do

```
String inputFile = inputFileName();
String outputFile = outputFileName();
```

Comment: Thanks figured it out. added while ((!inputFile.equals("exit") || (!outputFile.equals("exit"))) && !sentinel) since that was actually causing it an infinate loop

Answer (score 1):

That's a ton of code, but I think the problem might just be the condition in your while loop. You have:

`while (!inputFile.equals("exit") || (!outputFile.equals("exit")))`

So the loop will exit if you've put in exit for both the input file and the output file. However, you only check for input once, when the two files are first used. If you want the loop to take two new file names every time, you'll need to add that at the end of the while loop, something like harshit suggested. If you add `String inputFile = inputFileName();` and `String outputFile = outputFileName();`at the end of the while loop, you'll enter new file names each time the loop occurs and you should be able to exit it.